# Cropping a frame in video

Tags: python, opencv, crop

What I'm trying to achieve is to crop my roi in the video frame into a variable and then further send it as a parameter..

Consider  in face detection, and that x,y,x+w,y+h are the coordinates of the roi, which is the face and my aim is to crop that face and to show it.

The code below is just to explain my error and problem...

```
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("D:\\Downloads\\video2.mp4")
#x,y,w,h, will change according the video i.e. where the face is detected. 
#For the purpose of explaining, i took these values.
x=50
y=100
w=75
h=90
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _,frame=cap.read()
    
    crop_frame=frame[y:y+h,x:x+w] 
    
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.imshow("crop_frame",frame)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

But upon doing this, I get this error:

```
  crop_frame=frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This error wasn't there when i was working with images but on video inputs, i get this error.

Any solution to this problem or any alternative solution?

Comment: So clearly, the frame isn't a simple image. It's an object which probably contains a frame along with some other metadata. You need to find out the structure of  what `cap.read()` returns and modify your code accordingly

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: Check the dupe I've linked

Comment: i checked that link...It doesn't answer my question. I'm getting output of cv2.imshow("frame",frame). But crop_frame gives that error...

Comment: You're right about the dupe - I'd missed the `_,frame` but my original statement stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are slicing `None` when the video ends and no frame can be read: `None[y:y+h,x:x+w]`
You should use the `retval` to check if there is a frame to process, see the doc here: [cv::VideoCapture::read](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1).

So, try this code as experiment:

```
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame=cap.read()
    if ret:
      cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    else:
      print('None frame:', frame)
      break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

There is no rendering because there is no time to do so, that's why you need to look at the next example.

---

Follows a simple script as example. These are the main points:

- First, your loop is missing waytKey() function to allow the rendering, see the [doc
  here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7).
- If you want your variable outside the loop, you must define
  it outside the loop.
- Also, you should choose which frame to crop.

You can also add HighGui (https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html) controls for selecting the frame, etc.

```
import cv2

cap=cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
x=50
y=100
w=75
h=90

crop_frame = None

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if ret: to be added
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    keypressed = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if keypressed == ord('q'):
      break
    if keypressed == ord('f'):
      crop_frame = frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
      cv2.imshow("crop_frame", crop_frame)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()

cv2.imwrite('crop_frame.jpg', crop_frame)
```

You run and it shows the video.
Press 'F' and the current frame is cropped and presented in a new window.
Press 'Q': the loop exists and the cropped frame is saved as an image.

Comment: okay, i get your answer. But what I'm doing is, I'm using this concept to crop out the roi like when a face detected in a video, i would like to crop that face....the code i mentioned above is just an example I used to explain my query. The code u wrote above just captures the frame on those coordinates. Consider those co-ordinates as your roi, whose position changes according to the video. What should i do then?

Comment: Just answered your question. It's not clear what is the next problem. Maybe you want to update your question with more details.

Comment: Check my edit: Basically you are slicing `None` when the video ends and no frame can be read.

Comment: okay, i get your point. There is no rendering time for cropping. What i will do is i will implement the 2nd example of yours and write the code in such a way that it will detect faces but when i press F it will crop the face... I think that might work